# Good RESTful URI structure to check answer

Tags: rest, restful-url

I am building a game where users can submit answers to questions. I do not want to simply GET the answers for obvious reasons.

What would be a good RESTful URI the check whether the user's answer is the correct one?

So far I am successfully GETting resource data from URIs such as /games, /games/123/levels, and /games/123/levels/easy/345.

Would it still be considered RESTful to have a checkAnswer service located at /games/123/levels/east/345/checkAnswer even though it is a verb instead of a noun?

I know REST is just a concept but I'd like to know peoples' opinions.

Thanks

Comment: It does feel not RESTful to me. I would use a PUT request to /games/123/levels/east/345/answer for that, and not accepting a GET request to the same URL.

Comment: But using a PUT should be reserved for updating resource, in this case an answer. I simple want to get its value and compare it against a submitted value. This is a grey area for me.

Comment: If the answer itself is a simply string, then surely a `GET` request to `/games/123/levels/easy/345/<the answer>` will return a 200 response (or something in the 2xx range) if `<the answer>` is correct and a 404 if it's not the correct answer? Or do you not feel that to be appropriate?

Comment: I'm slowly learning REST and I'd like to make sure I'm using it correctly, or ensure I'm not going against principles. I'm willing to trust your solution but because it doesn't return a resource I didn't automatically think of it.

Comment: @AlexB if you're learning REST, I highly recommend this $5 ebook: http://www.amazon.com/The-REST-API-Design-Handbook-ebook/dp/B00890OBFI. Helps lay out a bunch of the fundamentals that you're trying to grok.

Comment: A successful GET should always return a resource. I know you're not bound to any rules but having a successful GET return nothing doesn't really make sense

Comment: Thanks Eric. Tim, it would return a boolean of true or false but it wouldn't return a resource. Perhaps adding the action ?action=checkAnswer is a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a route to questions, I would **POST** an answer to the url **`/questions/<question_id>/answers`** and if the answer is good return a status code of **`201 - Accepted`** and if it's incorrect I would return **`422 -  Unprocessable Entity`** or maybe a **`403 - Forbidden`** status code depending on what you view as the most fitting [status code description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

So in this example the question's ID would be 213 and the body of the **POST** request could be something like `{"answer": "B"}`.